# How can I print the values in my linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, pass-by-pointer

I have, for a large portion of the day, been trying to write a simple program with linked lists. My main issue seems to be not understanding why the memory I am accessing is not what I think it is. I am printf crazy and outputting every possible form of data I can and still am having trouble understanding why it will not work.

For example when I pass the `&head` to a function which takes `node **location` and I want to check whether the value inside `location` (and therefore `head`) is `NULL` or not, should I use `if(!*location) return;` or should I use `if(!location) return;`, It seems the later is correct, but why?

And when I want to create a `node *current` inside a function to keep track of things, should I start with `node* current = *head` or `node* current = head`, and most importantly, **why**? I have noticed that the later is better, but I cannot make sense of it still. Warnings go away when I typecast the statements, but it seems to fix nothing.

Here is some functions I have been writing, can you please give me hints on where I am not making sense in the code. Preferably, I hope to understand why the output seems to be a memory location and then accessing bad memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_struct
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node* return_create_neck(node **head, int value)
{
    node* ptr;
    *head = ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*head)->val = value;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

node* return_append_tail(node **location, int value)
{
    node* ptr;
    *location = ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*location)->val = value;
    (*location)->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

void print_linked_list(node **head)
{
    if(!head)
        return;

    node *current = head;
    while(current)
    {
        printf("%d ", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    node *head=NULL, *current=NULL;
    int i=0;
    for( current = return_create_neck(&head, 1);
        i < 4;
        current = return_append_tail(&current, i+1))
    { ++i; }

    printf("Pritning...\n");
    print_linked_list(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return_append_tail` function doesn't actually append anything, unless called with the correct `location`, which you do not.

You should call it with `&current->next` from the `main` function.

Comment: I need to understand why this is the correct location however, and my program is probably too riddled with bugs to notice if it fixed anything. I am having trouble knowing how to debug this problem.

Comment: @Leonardo When create the "head" node, you assign it to `current`. Then you call `return_append_tail` with `&current` and the function then _overwrites_ the `current` pointer with the new node it allocates. If you call the function with `&current->next` the function will put the newly allocated node in `current->next` thereby appending the new node to the list.

Comment: @Leonardo One way of debugging this would be to step though the code in a debugger, and you will hopefully notice that in `return_append_tail` the value of the `location` variable will never change, in other words it always points to the same location. You will also notice that `head->next` never will be set.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find a good debugger for this and learn to use it, I appreciate that you have explained it well.